# List item event receiver firing when list is modified

Tags: 2013, event-receivers

If I have an event receiver that handles the *item added* event, it fires whenever the list is modified. While debugging the event we see that it is firing over a non-existim item (`properties.ListItem` is `null`).

I have been handling this with the following one-liner:

```
if (properties.ListItem == null) return;
```

However, I feel that I am not getting the whole picture, and that I may end up causing more problems for not handling this correctly.

Is there a reason the *item added* event fires when the list is modified? Is there a better way to handle this, or to prevent this event from firing in this situation?

**Edit:** the change I am making to the list is adding a field programmatically during feature activation.

Comment: properties.ListItem in item adding event is always null. At that moment list item is still is not exists

Comment: @RuslanDayanov thanks for pointing that out! Indeed, that was an error on my part. I am fixing the question. However, the same event firing happens on *item added events* as well, when the item should exist.

Comment: What kind of changes are you making to list? I've tested event receiver and nothing has happened. And check your list event receivers with sharepoint manager.

Comment: I am adding a field programmatically, during feature activation. Sandbox solution.